# Coloring a UIBezierPath

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, core-graphics

I was wondering how this can be accomplished.

I am looking to color part of a UIBezierPath, not the whole thing.

For example, I'm interested in coloring from the beginning to middle of the path a different color.

Comment: Basically a section of the path, for example, from the beginning of the path to a point in the middle of a path (assuming straight line path).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll have to create separate paths, then draw them independently.

Comment: This is correct.  Neither UIBezierPath nor the underlying CGPath has any API for stroking only a part of the path.